# Using Email Channel sends MULTIPLE replies

Tags: c#, frameworks, botframework, bots

When replying to an email received through the email channel, the bot sends over 400 replies, spamming the inbox. I'm not sure why this happens although it seems like once one email is sent, the code enters a loop of replying and receiving emails and never ends.

I'm using SDK 4 .Net Core, running the code over Visual Studio Locally, using ngrok to debug locally while publishing to Azure Bot Channel portal.
Here's the code:

**EchoTestBot.cs**

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EchoTest.Dialogs;
using EchoTest.EmailJson;
using EchoTest.State;
using EchoTest.Utils;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EchoTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a bot that processes incoming activities.
    /// For each user interaction, an instance of this class is created and the OnTurnAsync method is called.
    /// This is a Transient lifetime service.  Transient lifetime services are created
    /// each time they're requested. For each Activity received, a new instance of this
    /// class is created. Objects that are expensive to construct, or have a lifetime
    /// beyond the single turn, should be carefully managed.
    /// For example, the <see cref="MemoryStorage"/> object and associated
    /// <see cref="IStatePropertyAccessor{T}"/> object are created with a singleton lifetime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1"/>
    public class EchoTestBot : IBot
    {
        // Define the IDs for the dialogs in the bot's dialog set.
        private const string MainDialogId = "mainDialog";
        private const string TicketDialogId = "ticketDialog";
        private const string FAQDialogId = "faqDialog";
        private const string AlarmDialogId = "alarmDialog";
        private const string EmailDialogNestedId = "emailnestedDialog";

        // Define the dialog set for the bot.
        private readonly DialogSet _dialogs;

        // Define the state accessors and the logger for the bot.
        private readonly BotAccessors _accessors;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HotelBot"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accessors">Contains the objects to use to manage state.</param>
        /// <param name="loggerFactory">A <see cref="ILoggerFactory"/> that is hooked to the Azure App Service provider.</param>
        public EchoTestBot(BotAccessors accessors, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (loggerFactory == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
            }

            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<EchoTestBot>();
            _logger.LogTrace($"{nameof(EchoTestBot)} turn start.");
            _accessors = accessors ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));

            // Define the steps of the main dialog.
            WaterfallStep[] steps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
        MenuStepAsync,
        HandleChoiceAsync,
        LoopBackAsync,
            };



            // Create our bot's dialog set, adding a main dialog, an email dialog and the three component dialogs.
            _dialogs = new DialogSet(_accessors.DialogStateAccessor)
                .Add(new WaterfallDialog(MainDialogId, steps))
                .Add(new EmailDialog(EmailDialogNestedId))
                .Add(new TicketDialog(TicketDialogId))
                .Add(new FAQDialog(FAQDialogId))
                .Add(new SetAlarmDialog(AlarmDialogId));
        }

        private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> MenuStepAsync(
            WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {

            if (stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelId == "email")
            {


                // Receives the ChannelData Json string, deserialize it into a ChannelDataJson object and cast it into a context.value to send it to the component Dialog
                stepContext.Values["channelData"] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChannelDataJson>(stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData.ToString());
                //((ChannelDataJson)stepContext.Values["channelData"]);
                var h = 0;
                await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(EmailDialogNestedId, stepContext.Values["channelData"]);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
            else
            { await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(); }
            // Present the user with a set of "suggested actions".
            List<string> options = new List<string> { "Check INC/CHG/RITM Status", "FAQ", "Chat with you (Under Construction)" };
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(options, "How can I help you?"),
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            return Dialog.EndOfTurn;
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleChoiceAsync(
            WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Get the user's info. (Since the type factory is null, this will throw if state does not yet have a value for user info.)
            UserInfo userInfo = await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, null, cancellationToken);

            // Check the user's input and decide which dialog to start.
            // Pass in the guest info when starting either of the child dialogs.
            string choice = (stepContext.Result as string)?.Trim()?.ToLowerInvariant();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "check inc/chg/ritm status":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(TicketDialogId, userInfo, cancellationToken);

                case "faq":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(FAQDialogId, userInfo, cancellationToken);

                case "chat with you (under construction)":
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(AlarmDialogId, userInfo.Guest, cancellationToken);

                default:
                    // If we don't recognize the user's intent, start again from the beginning.
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                        "Sorry, I don't understand that command. Please choose an option from the list.");
                    return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(MainDialogId, null, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoopBackAsync(
            WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Get the user's info. (Because the type factory is null, this will throw if state does not yet have a value for user info.)
            UserInfo userInfo = await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, null, cancellationToken);
            var h = 0;
            // Process the return value from the child dialog.
            switch (stepContext.Result)
            {
                //case TableInfo table:
                //    // Store the results of the reserve-table dialog.
                //    userInfo.Table = table;
                //    await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, userInfo, cancellationToken);
                //    break;
                //case WakeUpInfo alarm:
                //    // Store the results of the set-wake-up-call dialog.
                //    userInfo.WakeUp = alarm;
                //    await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, userInfo, cancellationToken);
                //    break;
                //The TicketDialog returns a FailoverTemp object and this case is activated
                case FailoverTemp failover:
                    // If the user failed to enter a valid ticket number, the FailoverTemp object returned will have a value of 1 and this if is activated.
                    if (failover.failOver == 1)
                    {

                        //We are using the UserInfo accessor to store persistent RetryAttempts so we can do something about it.
                        userInfo.RetryAttempts++;
                        await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, userInfo, cancellationToken);
                    }
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    //if the user entered a valid ticket number the TicketDialog should return a FailoverTemp value of 0 and no retryattempt should be logged
                    //    await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, userInfo, cancellationToken);
                    //}
                    break;

                default:
                    // We shouldn't get here, since these are no other branches that get this far.
                    break;
            }

            // Restart the main menu dialog.
            return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(MainDialogId, null, cancellationToken);
        }

        // Below starts the Email Dialog Waterfall steps. This will only trigger if the onTurnAsync detects the incoming activity message is of "email" channelid



            /// <summary>
            /// Every conversation turn for our Echo Bot will call this method.
            /// There are no dialogs used, since it's "single turn" processing, meaning a single
            /// request and response.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="turnContext">A <see cref="ITurnContext"/> containing all the data needed
            /// for processing this conversation turn. </param>
            /// <param name="cancellationToken">(Optional) A <see cref="CancellationToken"/> that can be used by other objects
            /// or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
            /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> that represents the work queued to execute.</returns>
            /// <seealso cref="BotStateSet"/>
            /// <seealso cref="ConversationState"/>
            /// <seealso cref="IMiddleware"/>
            public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {


                // Establish dialog state from the conversation state.
                DialogContext dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

                // Get the user's info.
                UserInfo userInfo = await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserInfo(), cancellationToken);

                await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, userInfo, cancellationToken);

                // Continue any current dialog.
                DialogTurnResult dialogTurnResult = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();

                // Process the result of any complete dialog.
                if (dialogTurnResult.Status is DialogTurnStatus.Complete)
                {
                    var i = 0;
                    //switch (dialogTurnResult.Result)
                    //{
                    //    case GuestInfo guestInfo:
                    //        // Store the results of the check-in dialog.
                    //        userInfo.Guest = guestInfo;
                    //        await _accessors.UserInfoAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, userInfo, cancellationToken);
                    //        break;

                    //    default:
                    //        // We shouldn't get here, since the main dialog is designed to loop.
                    //        break;
                    //}
                }

                // Every dialog step sends a response, so if no response was sent,
                // then no dialog is currently active.

                else if (!turnContext.Responded)
                {
                    var h = 0;
                    // if the user attempted to many times to enter an invalid ticket, this condition is met and the if should open a Too many attempts dialog.
                    //if (userInfo.RetryAttempts > 3)
                    //{
                        //We need to think how to handle too many attemps.
                        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialogId, null, cancellationToken);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    // Otherwise, start our bot's main dialog.
                    //    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialogId, null, cancellationToken);
                    //}
                }

                // Save the new turn count into the conversation state.
                await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                await _accessors.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            }


            else
            {
                // Commenting this to avoid "event detected" message over the chat.
            // await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{turnContext.Activity.Type} event detected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EmailDialog.cs**

```
using EchoTest.Utils;
using MarvinModels;
using MarvinServices;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EchoTest.Dialogs
{
    public class EmailDialog : ComponentDialog
    {


        // Nested Dialog Id, required to be used with the ReplaceDialog
        private const string EmailDialogId = "emailDialogId";

        public EmailDialog(string id) // id inhereted from the parent Dialog.
            : base(id)
        {
            // The InitialDialogId needs to be set to the ID of a dialog in the nested/child dialog, the one to start when the waterfall starts
            InitialDialogId = EmailDialogId;

            // Define the prompts used in this conversation flow.
            //AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(FAQPrompt));
            //AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(RepeatPrompt));

            // Define the conversation flow using a waterfall model.
            WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                CheckQuestionAsync,
                FAQChoicePromptAsync,

            };
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(EmailDialogId, waterfallSteps));



        }

        private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> CheckQuestionAsync(
        WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            ChannelDataJson email = new ChannelDataJson();
            stepContext.Values["emaildata"] = stepContext.Options;
            var j = 0;
            email = ((ChannelDataJson)stepContext.Values["emaildata"]);

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(email.TextBody.Text);
            var h = 0;
            //var strings = ChannelDataEmail.ToString();
            //var j = 0;
            //ChannelDataJson EmailObject = new ChannelDataJson();

            //EmailObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChannelDataJson>(strings);

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        }


        private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FAQChoicePromptAsync(
    WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {

            //return await stepContext.PromptAsync(FAQPrompt,
            //    new PromptOptions
            //    {
            //        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What do you want to know?"),
            //        RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Selected Option not available . Please try again."),
            //        Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(questions),

            //    },
            //cancellationToken);
            //await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                "What do you want to know?");
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to share more code. I can't see anything obvious at the moment. What does the `MainDialogId` class look like? Could you also fix the layout of the code, it's hard to follow.

Comment: Fixing the layout of the code may even give you insight into what's going on (if that's how you have it in your editor). The community usually attempts to reformat code for you but doing so here necessitates changes that could misrepresent the problem. You have an `else` block outside the `OnTurnAsync` method and we can't assume where that was meant to be as there are at least two places where it could be valid, and then there's still an extra `}`.

Comment: @Jammer - It's more likely that `MainDialogId` is a property based on how it's being used. The syntax highlighter is coloring it the same as classes, probably because it's PascalCase.

Comment: I know. Still need to see whatever it is.

Comment: Added Requested Code!

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already fixed part of this on GH [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1331) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1347) but I'm going to put the answer here for other people's edification:

Your infinite loop is caused by putting the channel check inside a waterfall dialog.

In MenuStepAsync, the combination of:

```
return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
```

at the end of your (channelId == email) check and it's subsequent else block:

```
else
            { await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(); }
```

was ending your waterfall dialog, true, however, the lack of response to each and every one of those looped emails meant that as soon as no reply was sent, it started over and resent the initial message to your endpoint. And over and over and over. As you put in your GH issue, the channel check should be in `OnTurnAsync`. Additionally, `ContinueDialogAsync` does not behave the same in `WaterfallStepContext` as it does in `DialogContext`. The correct method is `stepContext.NextAsync()`;